# First order ODE and hyper geometric function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible that the solution to a first order differential equation involves a hyper geometric function? I thought that only second order ODE solution contains hypergeometric function. I am relying on Wolfram to find the solution.

Comment: I think you need to put more conditions on your equation. I suspect your cited claim is only true for linear DE, and you are dealing with a non-linear Riccati DE or similar.

Comment: Which equation, which hypergeometric function? $\exp,\arcsin, \ln$ are all hypergeometric functions and solutions of simple first order differential equations.

Comment: Solve the linear equation -3/4 x^n ( dy(x))/( dx) - 3/20 x^(n - 1) ( dy(x))/( dx) + x^n (n - 1) - 3/20 x^(n - 2) (n - 1) y(x) - 3/4 x^(n - 1) (n - 1) y(x) = 0, such that y(0) = 0:

Answer (score 1):

A first-order Riccati equation "reduces" to a second-order linear equation, which might be hypergeometric.  For example, the Riccati equation

$$ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}v \left( x \right) = \left( v \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}-{\frac { \left(  \left( a+b+1 \right) x-c
 \right) v \left( x \right) }{{x}^{2}-x}}+{\frac {ab}{{x}^{2}-x}}=0
$$

has solutions $v = -u'/u$ where $u$ satisfies the hypergeometric equation

$$ (x^2-x) u'' + ((a+b+1) x - c) u' + ab u = 0$$

and so one of its solutions is 
$$ - \;{}_2F_1(a,b; c; x)^{-1} \dfrac{d}{dx} {}_2F_1(a,b; c; x) = -{\frac {ab\;{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(b+1,a+1;\,c+1;\,x)}}{
{c\; \mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,c;\,x)}}}
$$